# Stretch Bitmap at specific corner

Tags: android, matrix, bitmap, camera, transform

Is it possible to stretch a Bitmap at a specific corner? The picture below shows my intention:

[image]

I shoot a picture with the camera, detect the corners in the image and want to transform the content. As far as I know this can't be achieved with the [Matrix](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html) class alone. The [Camera](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Camera.html) class should help, but I would need to calculate the camera's position. Is there an algorithm for this purpose? How would you do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You made me look into this very interesting problem and it seems easy to do it in Android. Use absolute coordinates for the four points of the Mesh:

```
float[] mVerts = {
       topLeftX, topLeftY, 
       topRightX, topRightY, 
       bottomLeftX, bottomLeftY, 
       bottomRightX, bottomRightY
       };

canvas.drawBitmapMesh(myImage, 1, 1, mVerts, 0, null, 0, null);
```

You would have to figure out how to get these points but drawBitmapMesh will stretch it for you.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the easiest way of doing such transformation on Android is to use OpenGL. You can treat your bitmap as a texture. Then you can use the detected corners as texture coordinates. Assign each of them as texture coordinate to the corresponding vertex of a simple rectangular shape. Then ask OpenGL to draw it on your canvas. Pseudocode:

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, pictureId);
glBegin(GL_QUAD);
glVertex(0,0); // left upper corner
glTexCoord(corners[0].x/picture.getWidth(), corners[0].y/picture.getHeight());
glVertex(1,0); // right upper corner
glTexCoord(corners[1].x/picture.getWidth(), corners[1].y/picture.getHeight());
glVertex(1,1); // right lower corner
glTexCoord(corners[2].x/picture.getWidth(), corners[2].y/picture.getHeight());
glVertex(0,1); // left lower corner
glTexCoord(corners[3].x/picture.getWidth(), corners[3].y/picture.getHeight());
glEnd();
```

You don't need any Camera nor complicated transforms. Of course it's not very convenient as using OpenGL for such easy task is quite an overkill. But, there's not really an easier way except writing such texturing by yourself. If you wish, you can start reading from wiki and go to external links and look for example software implementation of texturing methods:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texture_mapping

You can also try to use any of OpenGL effect views, it will simplify setup, but also ask you for a shader or two:

http://code.google.com/p/effect-view/